# Spring @Transactional does not work when I call a method inside of it. How can I slove it?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have an entity with 3 field (id, name and age). I have created a repository (PersonRepository) in which I want to see how Transaction works.
I find strange that if I insert a method call inside a method, this does not work as expected.

```
public void nestedTransaction() {
        personRepository.save(new Person(11L, "A1", 26));
        childTransaction();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void childTransaction() {
    personRepository.save(new Person(10L, "A2", 26));
    throw new RuntimeException("ExceptionTest child");
}
```

After the autowiring of PersonRepository that contain the above methods, I call:

```
try {
    serviceTransaction.nestedTransaction();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Please do not pay attention on the fact that I'm using System.out.println instead of logging, this is just a test for understanding @Transactional. However, I expect that in my DB there is the entity (11L, "A1", 26) but not the entity (10L, "A2", 26)) instead I have both. Why this happen?

I already know that I can use transactionTemplate and it works using it. For example:

```
public void nestedTransaction() {
    transactionTemplate.setTimeout(1000);
    transactionTemplate.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ);
    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    personRepository.save(new Person(11L, "Ale2", 26));
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            
       @Override
       protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            childTransaction();
       }
    });
}
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `@Transactional` annotation above the `nestedTransaction()` method as well for the transaction to commit. Also, the `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED` property is default, so you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction works only if you call it outside from the class. Default Spring use AOP to start and finish the transaction, which is an around advice. So when you call method inside the class, it can't go throught that proxy. You have to annotate the method you call outside from the class with transactional, any method called from that method inside that class (and lower in calling stack outside that class which dont create new transaction) will join to that transaction.
You can use nasted transaction with, modify isolation levels etc, but not in same class.

You can visualize something like:

[image]